# can't implement django inside html

Tags: python, html, django

I have a problem where I can't use my Django variables inside Html 
This is my code :
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse

# Create your models here.


class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=255, unique=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    content = models.TextField(default="---")
    H_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    L_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    remaining = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    original_price = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    Ended = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    Published = models.BooleanField(default=True)


    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']

        def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s'% self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('Products.views.post', args=[self.slug])
```

**Views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Post


# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    posts=Post.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'Index.html', {"Posts": posts})

def post(request):
    return
```

**Index.html**

```
<h1>This is just a title </h1>

{% for post in posts %}
    <div>
        <h3> {{ post.title }}</h3>
        <h3> {{ post.content }}</h3>
    </div>

{% endfor %}
```

I know this isn't the best way to do Html but the goal is just to get it to work then I will style it with css and make everything Look Clean When i run the server i only get "this is just a title"
Any suggestions to help me fix it will be apreciated 
Note that I am a begginer in django

Comment: How do you know that `posts` is not empty?

Comment: `Posts` in `def index` but `posts` in template

Comment: Case of "Posts" looks wrong. Post the error you are getting in future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables in the Django template language are case sensitive. You use `{% for post in posts %}` in your template, therefore you need to use `posts` not `Posts` in your view.

```
return render(request, 'Index.html', {"posts": posts})
```

Comment: I can Never thank you enough . Thank you so much I was struggling with this for the past day